# How to have Jersey pass malformed headers

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jersey-1.0

I'm using Jersey 1.12 and have an endpoint that may or may not receive malformed headers from clients that i don't control (for instance `"Content-Type":"application/json; bla-bla"`)
Obviously `bla-bla` is malformed as the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) requires parameters to have values as well i.e. `bla-bla=value` and thus Jersey will output something like

```json
"status": 400,
"message": "Bad Content-Type header value: 'application/json; bla-bla'"
```

I can write a filter to tackle this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665744/how-to-inject-an-object-into-jersey-request-context), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350019/jersey-pass-value-from-containerrequestfilter-to-endpoint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551839/how-can-you-pass-data-from-a-filter-to-the-endpoint-in-jersey) but I wonder if there's a way to have Jersey just **ignore** the malformed header all together in cases where i'm not interested in it's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's apparently no solution for this I ended up wrapping the ServletRequest in one of our application's filters kinda like what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter) to have it return a modified header where needed.

As a workaround I guess it's fine and not *very* intrusive but I still wonder if there was a better way?